# Is it possible to write a Java class in JScheme?

Tags: java, scheme

Can you write a Java class in JScheme?  It would be nice to be able to so that you could write a listener in JScheme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. According to the following you can write a Java class in JScheme: http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/Scripting/jscheme/Catalogjscheme.htm

Comment: That requires a macro in a file that 404s.

Comment: If you want to add an ActionListener, you can do it as they show it here: http://jscheme.sourceforge.net/jscheme/doc/javadot.html